# how to convert tensorflow .meta .data .index to .ckpt file?

Tags: python, tensorflow

As we know, when using `tensorflow` to save checkpoint, we have 3 files, for e.g.:

**model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001**

**model.ckpt.index**

**model.ckpt.meta**

I check on the faster `rcn`n and found that they have an evaluation.py script which helps evaluate the pre-trained model, but the script only accept .ckpt file (as they provided some pre-trained models above).

I have run some finetuning from their pre-trained model

And then I wonder if there's a way to convert all the `.data-00000-of-00001`, .index and .meta into one single .ckpt file to run the evaluate.py script on the checkpoint?

(I also notice that the pre-trained models they provided in the repo do have only 1 `.ckpt` file, how can they do that when the save-checkpoint function generates 3 files?)

Comment: It is very hard to help you without knowing what your evaluation.py does.

Comment: passing it the full file name of the .data-XXXXX probably still works

Answer (score 0):

These

{
model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001

model.ckpt.index

model.ckpt.meta
}

are the more recent checkpoint format

while

{model.ckpt}

is a previous checkpoint format

It will be in the same concept as to convert a Nintendo Switch to NES ... Or a 3 pieces CD bundle to a single ROM cartridge...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert, You can save the variables in the network using

```
saver = tf.train.Saver() 
saver.save(sess, 'path of save/fileName.ckpt')
```

To restore the network for reuse later or in another script, use:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('path of save/')
sess.run(....)
```

Important points:

1. sess must be same between first and later runs (coherent structure).
2. saver.restore needs the path of the folder of the saved files, not
   an individual file path.